# Is it possible to use Stackdriver with Kotlin?

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm using Spring Boot with Kotlin and the app is deployed to Google App Engine Standard. I know that I can debug with Stackdriver using Java but can I use Stackdriver to debug my production code in Kotlin? I would like to use snapshots and logpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of March 2016, Kotlin is not supported yet for StackDriver Debug, only Java.

Comment: It is now possible to use Kotlin in the standard environment. An example is provided at [GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/kotlin-appengine-standard) on github.

Comment: But do they support Stackdriver Debug?

Comment: I tried to debug that kotlin example in Stackdriver Debug, and it was not possible. Like Balint Pato said it’s not supported.